# Disabling alternating background color in gridview rows yii2

Tags: html, css, gridview, yii2

I was able to modify the row color of gridview but I think there is a default property that handles alternating row color because what I indicated on my style is red but when it was displayed the even rows are in red while the alternate row is white. The white colored row should be green. I think this was made by yii for some readability purposes.

Weird thing though is that, the font color is followed based on the class I provided.

```
<style>
.stateCritical:nth-child(even) {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}

.stateCritical:nth-child(odd) {
    color: blue;
    background-color: green;
}

.stateOk {
    color: black;
    background-color: #C0FFBE;
}
</style>

<?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'rowOptions' => function($model) {
                    if ($model->last_hard_state == 2){
                        return ['class' => 'stateCritical'];
                    }
                    return ['class' => 'stateOk'];    
                },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
?>
```

How can I override the default background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
 you are not able to overwrite that default class of grid view. So make your color attribute Important so it will apply first , or you can 
    
    .stateCritical:nth-child(even) {
        color: black;
        background-color: red;
    }

```
.stateCritical:nth-child(odd) {
    color: blue;
    background-color: green !important;
}

.stateOk {
    color: black;
    background-color: #C0FFBE !important;
}
</style>
```

Explanation:

This is the real life scenario

Imagine this scenario

```
you have a global CSS file that sets visual aspects of your site globally
you (or others) use inline styles on elements themselves which is usually very bad practice
```

In this case you could set certain styles in your global CSS file as important thus overriding inline styles set directly on elements.
Actual real world example?

This kind of scenario usually happens when you don't have total control over your HTML. Think of solutions in Sharepoint for instance. You'd like your part to be globally defined (styled) but some inline styles you can't control are present. !important makes such situations easier to deal with.

Other real life scenarios would also include some badly written jQuery plugins that also use inline styles...

I suppose you got the idea by now and can come up with some others as well.
When do you decide to use !important?

I suggest you don't use !important unless you can't do it any other way. Whenever it's possible to avoid it, avoid it. Using lots of !important styles will make maintenance a bit harder, because you break the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

Comment: Nice! I'd like to accept this answer but it would be kind of you if you'll edit your answer and add explanation about the `!important`. :)

Comment: I added the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

A far easier way to do this is to override the class of the `gridView` widget. It gets the stripes because the default class for the grid is `table table-striped`.

Simply add this to your widget declaration;

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-bordered']
]);
```